# Error while getting available partitions. Apache Stratos

Tags: apache, apache-axis, wso2-stratos

I'm facing this error while try to config my Stratos -  Partition Deployment it is always give me this error :

Error while getting available partitions. Cause : The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) https://x.x.x.x:9443/services/AutoscalerService/

any suggested ideas ?!

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like stratos manager cannot reach Autoscaler on the given endpoint. Is it possible for you to check whether you can telnet from the stratos manager host to Autoscaler IP, 9443?

If you could mention the stratos version and the deployment model (single jvm/distributed) you are using, we could provide a much better answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm using Apache Stratos 4.0 and I'm new on it, with single jvm... I tried to telnet that port and it give me 
((Connection closed by foreign host.)) I opened the port, but same thing ! I'm not sure what is the problem here

Answer (score 0):

The cause is the wrong definition of the autoscaler endpoint in the /repository/conf/cartridge-config.properties file. Check if the specified IP address is reachable from the stratos manager, and check that /etc/hosts is updated with the specified domain name in the cartridge-config.properties.

Comment: thank you very much... I checked the autoscaler endpoint and it was autoscaler.service.url=https://x.x.x.x:9443/services/AutoscalerService/
I don't know is it good or bad ! but I didn't change it BTW the autoscaler and stratos is in the same machine, is that affect ?

Comment: If you are using Apache Stratos 4.0.0 the Autoscaler service URL would be: https://<hostname>:<port>/services/AutoScalerService. Note the first "S" character. You could see the WSDL here: https://github.com/apache/stratos/tree/4.0.0/service-stubs/org.apache.stratos.autoscaler.service.stub/src/main/resources